# How to save scroll of Scroll View properly

Tags: android

How to save scroll state of scrollview properly.In my code, I'm using :

```
scroll_x = scrollView.getScrollX();
scroll_y = scrollView.getScrollY();
```

when activity pause,i'm `stored x and y` as you can `see` here, and when activity start, `i'm scroll` scrollView to `x` and `y`.
But crux is `(main problem)` is, scrollview not scrollview to x and y properly, it `scroll up or down` a little bit `automatically`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the instance state by using this class:

```
class SaveScrollNestedScrollViewer : NestedScrollView {
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributes)

constructor(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributes, defStyleAttr)


public override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
    return super.onSaveInstanceState()
  }

public override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
  }
}
```

use on your xml:

```
<yourClassNamePlace.SaveScrollNestedScrollViewer
     android:id="@+id/my_scroll_viewer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
</yourClassNamePlace.SaveScrollNestedScrollViewer>
```

and then use in activity like this:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        var myScrollViewerInstanceState: Parcelable? = null
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)

        if (myScrollViewerInstanceState != null) {
            my_scroll_viewer.onRestoreInstanceState(myScrollViewerInstanceState)
        }
    }

    public override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        myScrollViewerInstanceState = my_scroll_viewer.onSaveInstanceState()
    }
}
```